# how do i get a list of countries in my website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to find a way to display all countries list in a dropdown. Is there any short code in php or jquery to get a list of countries on my webpage? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show your current attempts, if any.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [countries-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/countries-list) npm package.

```
import countries from "countries-list";
```

Get extensive information about countries:

```
console.log(countries.countries);
```

Will get you:

```
{
   AD: {
      name: "Andorra"
      native: "Andorra"
      phone: "376"
      continent: "EU"
      capital: "Andorra la Vella"
      currency: "EUR"
      languages: ["ca"]
      emoji: ""
      emojiU: "U+1F1E6 U+1F1E9"
   }
   ...
}
```

Or just list of countries:

```
const countryCodes = Object.keys(countries.countries);
const countryNames = countryCodes.map(code => countries.countries[code].name);
console.log(countryNames);
```

Will print list of country names:

```
"Andorra"
"United Arab Emirates"
"Afghanistan"
"Antigua and Barbuda"
...
```

These needs to be sorted alphabetically as they are sorted based on country codes:

```
console.log(countryNames.sort());
```

Answer (score 20):

Up to date answer.

Browsers that support Intl can now offer you the countries in the language of your choice.

```
function getCountries(lang = 'en') {
    const A = 65
    const Z = 90
    const countryName = new Intl.DisplayNames([lang], { type: 'region' });
    const countries = {}
    for(let i=A; i<=Z; ++i) {
        for(let j=A; j<=Z; ++j) {
            let code = String.fromCharCode(i) + String.fromCharCode(j)
            let name = countryName.of(code)
            if (code !== name) {
                countries[code] = name
            }
        }
    }
    return countries
}
```

Calling `getCountries()` will return an object list of country codes with their names eg.

```
{AC: 'Ascension Island', AD: 'Andorra', AE: 'United Arab Emirates', AF: 'Afghanistan', AG: 'Antigua & Barbuda', …}
```

Comment: This is awesome. For context to others looking here, the solution loops over all possible combinations of two characters (`AA, AB, AC, …`) and checks if `Intl` knows it as a valid country code.

Comment: If you also want a list of names mapped to country codes, you can do `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(COUNTRY_CODES_TO_NAMES).map(entry => [entry[1], entry[0]]))` where `COUNTRY_CODES_TO_NAMES` is the output of @Gerardlamo 's function.

Comment: Too bad, codes can be wrong because FF & Chrome retained previously used ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes for various countries (Antarctica, Panama, ...), so if building Array of Arrays you get double & triple entries, or if building an Object, as in this answer, the last lexical code wins. This answer might still be useful for just names (without relying on the codes), or to generate a starting point literal string.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest using:

https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list

It gives you the list of countries in different formats (Text, JSON, PHP ...)

Or if you want just a quick HTML list then go to:

http://www.textfixer.com/resources/country-dropdowns.php

You can literally just copy paste those values into wherever you want, or you can call that page.

Comment: well kamal do i need to insert all the countries in database as i have to use it in php?

Answer (score 1):

Following on from [Ruslan Kazakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262437/ruslan-kazakov).

If you're using typescript and the [countries-list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/countries-list) npm package, I found that the following made the typescript compiler happy if you were looking to get a list of country names for a dropdown.

```js
const countryNames = Object.values(countries.countries)
  .map((item) => item.name))
  .sort();
```

Answer (score -5):

In struts2 you can get it -
e.g.,

```
<s:select name="name" headerKey="-1"
list="countryList" id="country" 
value="%{countryList}" 
></s:select>
```

In jQuery you will have to get the list via a ajax call and iterate over it 
e.g,

```
$.ajax({
           url: 'rcmidAuditTrail.action',
           type: 'GET',
           async : false,
           dataType: 'json',
           error: function(data) {
              console.log('error');
           },
           success: function(list) {

var html = '<select>'
              $.each(list,function(i,value){
                     html+='<option>'+value+'</option>';
              });
$('dropdownId').html(html);
           }
        });
```